# How to approximate Heaviside function by polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, approximation, linear-approximation

I have a Heaviside smooth function that defined as
$$H_{\epsilon}=\frac {1}{2} [1+\frac {2}{\pi} \arctan(\frac {x}{\epsilon})]$$

[image]

I want to use polynominal to approximate the Heaviside function. Could you suggest to me a solution? Thanks

UPDATE: This is Bombyx mori result in blue line and my expected result is red line

[image]

Comment: You probably know this already, but another excellent choice for such a function is $0.5*[1+tanh(x/epsilon)]$.

Comment: Yes. However, they are trigonometry. I want to use polynomial to approximate it

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:
$$
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}(\frac{x}{\epsilon}-\frac{x^3}{3\epsilon^{3}}+\frac{x^{5}}{5\epsilon^5}\cdots)
$$

Comment: what is $e$ in your formula? Thank

Comment: Should be replaced by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Sneaky.. $\,\,\,$

Comment: well, just want to kill time while preparing for TA work. :(

Comment: It looks wrong result. I tried to draw it but the result is not similar my goal result. Let see my update to see your result

Comment: I hope that you realize that every polynomial approximation has only a limited range over which it works well. Then it quickly shoots away to infinity. That is the nature of polynomials. They can't help it.

Comment: Great point. For my problem, which is range of $x$. Is it $[-1$  $1]$?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use polynomial as Heaviside step function with a good average precision, because any polynomial is infinite at both positive and negative infinity and Heaviside is not. Second, you would need to have zero value for all negative values. Even if you take that the value is only approximately zero you would need all larger and larger degree to achieve that.

In that sense the only option is to use rational function of two polynomials.

If you still insist of having just one polynomial expression then you can use normal Lagrange/Newton approximations taking as many points as you want. This can give you some accuracy within some region, and for the jump around $0$ you need to take more points around $0$.

Here is the polynomial for:

$$(0,1/2) (-1,0) (-2,0) (-3,0) (-4,0) (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1) (5,1)$$

$$\frac{x^9}{51840}-\frac{13x^7}{12096}+\frac{71x^5}{3456}-\frac{107x^3}{648}+\frac{1627x}{2520}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Is it possible to get the coefficients directly?

Sure, just create a linear system and solve it against the unknown coefficients. Notice that there is an infinite polynomial given by Taylor expansion of any of the approximations like the one using $\tanh(kx)$ with extremely slow convergence.

In essence, since we ask a polynomial to be too much flat, a polynomial is a bad approximation to step function no matter what we do. A rational polynomial function is much better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Althogh I think Bombyx mori's solution is great and simple, maybe the following approximation is better for you on the interval $[-1,1]$.
$$
p_\varepsilon(x) = -\tfrac{1}{6\pi}\left(16\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{2\varepsilon}\right)-8\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)\right)x^3 - \tfrac{1}{6\pi}\left(2\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)-16\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{2\varepsilon}\right)\right)x+\tfrac12.
$$
I've got this by making a [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) for the data points: $$(-1,H_\varepsilon(-1)), (-1/2,H_\varepsilon(-1/2)), (0,H_\varepsilon(0)),(1/2,H_\varepsilon(1/2)), (1,H_\varepsilon(1)).$$